# Create Fiware Lab Instance

Tags: web-services, web, virtual-machine, fiware

I'm looking for some guidelines on how to create a FIWARE instance on a local server. Or do you really have to use an account and deploy a global FIWARE Lab your VM?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a tutorial finding plattform. Use Google^W ixquick instead.

Answer (score 3):

Currently in FIWARE Lab it is not possible to upload your own instance image. For this reason if you plan to have an instance in FIWARE Lab your choice should be to create it directly in FIWARE Lab.

Just for completion of reply I can tell you that since FIWARE Lab is based on OpenStack, theoretically you could create an Openstack compliant instance on your local machine (for instance starting from a virtual box VM), convert it and then upload its disk image to an Openstack cloud infrastructure.
There are many guides on the web explaining it in detail, this one explain you the high level process: https://www.mirantis.com/openstack-portal/express-openstack-portal/quickly-create-openstack-image/

Comment: Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 1):

another simple option (instead of installing the full openstack) is to use containers on your pc :) all FIWARE enablers are available as containers (https://hub.docker.com/u/fiware/). of course you can create also your own container (e.g. a django container for an interface) and then deploy snapshot the image and deploy it on FIWARE Lab.

Best,
Federico